# Where is the SubSonic 3 Test Database "SubSonic"?

Tags: subsonic3

I may be a little dense at times but where do I get the SubSonic database referenced by the SubSonic 3 test project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database is created on the fly using our migrations stuff. So - just create a DB called "SubSonic" and the tests do the rest. See the Setup() routine to see how this works - the tables are created on every test.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually find everything you need in SubSonic's github.  I think the DbScripts directory probably has what you need.

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/tree/master